# Navigation drawer from right to left with v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

I am implementing navigation drawer in my app where I want to use Material Design.

I used the following reference to create navigation drawer [link](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html).

It worked fine for me. Navigation drawer is working fine with left to right swipe.

Now as I have to implement my navigation drawer with right to left swipe. I made following changes. Hear is my code

file : `MainActivity.java`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String TITLES[] = {"Home","Events","Mail","Shop","Travel"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

    //Similarly we Create a String Resource for the name and email in the header view
    //And we also create a int resource for profile picture in the header view

    String NAME = "Akash Bangad";
    String EMAIL = "akash.bangad@android4devs.com";
    int PROFILE = R.mipmap.ic_profile;

    private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Assinging the toolbar object ot the view
    and setting the the Action bar to our toolbar
     */
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("cek", "home selected");
                if (Drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    Drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    Drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
        });




        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }



        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        /*Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle*/

       /* mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher, //navigation menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                Log.e("onDrawerClosed", "onDrawerClosed");
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                Log.e("onDrawerOpened","onDrawerOpened");



            }
        };*/

        /*mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer, toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                    if (Drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                        Drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    } else {
                        Drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                Log.e("onDrawerClosed", "onDrawerClosed");
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                Log.e("onDrawerOpened","onDrawerOpened");



            }
        };*/

        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State
       /* setActionBarUpIndicator((Drawable) mSlider,
                Drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT) ?
                        mCloseDrawerContentDescRes : mOpenDrawerContentDescRes);*/


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            //open close drawer
            if (Drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                Drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else {
                Drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

file : `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:elevation="7dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar">
        </include>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here I used android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle import for ActionBarDrawerToggle. But insted of this if if I use android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle I am able to work with this then the problem is that I am not getting the back button effect which is by default in material design.

And if I use V4 library then I can't use toolbar directly and also have to enable and show home button.

Basically I can't make Gravity.RIGHT if I use V7 library. How can I override that method.

file : error log

```
06-17 17:06:22.772    3296-3296/com.demo.nasir.materialdesign E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.demo.nasir.materialdesign, PID: 3296
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1322)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.toggle(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:289)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.access$100(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:65)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$1.onClick(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:201)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the gravity in xml only? This was the only change I needed to get the drawer to swipe the other way round.

Comment: android:layout_gravity="right"

Comment: @Capricorn

tried this also. Still having the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: @Johnson  tried this also. Still having the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: I am running into the same problem. Debugging this, I looked into the code for ActionBarDrawerToggle and it seems to be ONLY supporting drawer from Left to right!

Answer (score 0):

**Drawer positioning and layout is controlled using the android:layout_gravity attribute on child views corresponding to which side of the view you want the drawer to emerge from: left or right. (Or start/end on platform versions that support layout direction.)**

in XML change the gravity  to RIGHT

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Left drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <!-- Right drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and in java

add this too

If you're using Navigation Drawer project created by Android Studio, then things will change in onOptionsItemSelected. Since they created the child class, you have to use this code

```
if (item != null && id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } else {
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
}
```

Next. In class NavigationDrawerFragment, you have to create 3 methods:

Method 1

```
public boolean isDrawerOpen(int gravity) {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(gravity);
}
```

Method 2

```
public void closeDrawer(int gravity) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(gravity);
}
```

Method 3

```
public void openDrawer(int gravity) {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(gravity);
}
```